# XMLTYPE column parsing by oracle sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, xmltype

We are trying to parse an `XMLTYPE` column of the format below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<simple-record xmlns="http://www.system.com/schemas/policy">
  <record rule-id="1" rule-name="Test1 rule" rule-desc="This is the test rules." entitled-id="261" user-ent-id="" first-name="test1" last-name="test1" user-disp-name="test1, test1" ent-id="421" ent-type="app1" ent-name="Pay I" res-name="" act-name="" V-ent-type="role1" V-ent-id="421" V-ent-name="" V-res-name="" V-act-name="" bucket-id="1" app-id="61" app-name="Pay" state="OP"/>
  <record rule-id="2" rule-name="Test2 rule" rule-desc="This is the test rules." entitled-id="261" user-ent-id="" first-name="test2" last-name="test2" user-disp-name="test2, test2" ent-id="423" ent-type="app2" ent-name="Pay V" res-name="" act-name="" V-ent-type="role2" V-ent-id="423" V-ent-name="" V-res-name="" V-act-name="" bucket-id="2" app-id="61" app-name="Pay" state="OP"/>
</simple-record>


The query we tried is 
select td.ID, x.* from PV_CHANGE_REQUEST td,
XMLTABLE ('/simple-record/recod' 
          PASSING td.VIOLATIONS
            COLUMNS "ruleName" varchar2(100)  PATH '@rule-name')x
```

But the above query is giving 0 results. Please let me know if there is anything that I am missing.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<simple-record xmlns="http://www.system.com/schemas/policy">
  <record rule-id="1" rule-name="Test1 rule" rule-desc="This is the test rules." entitled-id="261" user-ent-id="" first-name="test1" last-name="test1" user-disp-name="test1, test1" ent-id="421" ent-type="app1" ent-name="Pay I" res-name="" act-name="" V-ent-type="role1" V-ent-id="421" V-ent-name="" V-res-name="" V-act-name="" bucket-id="1" app-id="61" app-name="Pay" state="OP"/>
</simple-record>

Comment: On first glance you seem to have mistyped /simple-record/recod.